How to exclude module from support library

I have a support library, and one of the module say moduleA, and moduleA contains C++ CDM files only, i will load these files dynamically. so currently, in my support library settings.gradle, i called include :moduleA and etc. and this moduleA is only being used in support library.
Now, I have a project, and it uses this support library. now i want to exclude moduleA from the build (I want my app level to control if I want to exclude). Note, as moduleA is only C++ files and only used in support library, so implementation(support library) { exclude moduleA } won't work for my case.

How could i achieve this? plz help me! thanks!

to answer my own questions. i think there is no solution to above situation. and i made a mistake that have the same name for that module, hence it is also being build even without using implementation project(...)

This doesn't really sound like an answer. Please read [answer].
